# How to add source code while creating OCI function using OCI SDK for JAVA

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a function in OCI with OCI SDK for java. The only option I see is adding an image url. There is no option to add zip/source as bytes. Is there any workaround to create the function with zip file.

```
CreateFunctionDetails createFunctionDetails = CreateFunctionDetails.builder()
            .displayName(lambdaFunctionResponse.configuration().functionName())
            .applicationId("ocid1.test.oc1..<unique_ID>EXAMPLE-applicationId-Value")
            .image("EXAMPLE-image-Value")
            .imageDigest("EXAMPLE-imageDigest-Value")
            .sourceDetails(PreBuiltFunctionSourceDetails.builder()
                .memoryInMBs(298L)
                .config(functionConfigMap)
                .timeoutInSeconds(30)
.provisionedConcurrencyConfig(ConstantProvisionedConcurrencyConfig.builder()
                .count(615).build())
                .traceConfig(FunctionTraceConfig.builder()
                .isEnabled(true).build())
                .build();
```

I have tried upgrading and downgrading the version of the OCI SDK, but I do not see any version having a difference in the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have to login to oci console and use the code editor to create function from scratch or you can create using existing images.

Other way you can install fn locally and setup oci and fn cli and develop in your local code editor or IDE and deploy from there.

If you want to create using oci sdk you can only create using the image by giving the image ocir name. you can refer this blog - https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/oracle-functions-invoking-functions-with-the-oci-sdk

Comment: The requirement is to add the source code as zip file/ bytes[].

Comment: This is not supported. you can't create using zip file.

Comment: One way i can think of that you can write your own custom docker file and download the zip and extract while building the docker image for function. That could be a way around for your requirement. Please refer the docs for BYO docker file for creating function